# how to implement one login for a username

Tags: node.js, express

I am storing all the session id's in a variable with the username and system ip, I am using this data for only one login for username. Now I have two problems where sometimes the new session in the browser is generated automatically without user action or if user removes the cookie related to my server. So the user is with the new session, I need to remove the username, system ip and session id from my list.

Answer (score 1):

Since the user didn't do anything explicit on your site you can't know the difference between "lost the cookie" and "haven't been to the site for a while".  The best you can do with a scheme like this is to just expire sessions that haven't been active for a week, a month or a year or whatever is appropriate.

You should consider to use an encrypted/hashed cookie with the user id of the logged in user instead of a session if you want to allow users to stay logged in "forever" without taking resources on the server.

Comment: thanks for the comment, actually session cookie is generated by the express framework, I not generating it. But for the session timeout, I can't prefer that, its already defined for 24 hours, Because I can't decline that time since my application user has to enter more than 200 entries in one screen.

Comment: You decide how long you tell the browser to keep the cookie for, no?  If it's just 24 hours you should be able to just delete any session that hasn't been modified/accessed for that long.

Comment: To use signed cookies, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897965/what-are-signed-cookies-in-connect-expressjs