# req.signedCookies not being read in expressJS

Tags: cookies, express

This is my setup:

express.js version": "3.0.0rc2"

**`app.js`**

```
...  
app.use(express.cookieParser('secret'));
app.use(express.session({secret: 'secret'}));
app.use(app.router);
...
```

Then to set the signed cookie and a redirect:
`res.cookie('session', cookie_value, {signed: true});`
`res.redirect('/else_where');`

Then to retrieve the signed cookie:
`var cookie = req.signedCookies.session;`

```
console.log('get cookie: ' + req.cookies.session);
console.log('get signed cookie: ' + req.signedCookies.session);
```

The problem is that the cookie is `undefined` for the signed cookie and works fine with the `req.cookies.session`.

For some reason I the signing of the cookie is not being played out.
Not sure what's going on.
Is the order of my `app.use()` correctly laid out?

similar to this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897965/what-are-signed-cookies-in-connect-expressjs)

**UPDATE_02**
I implemented a simple `res/req` for a signed cookie like so:

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.cookieParser('secret'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(expressValidator);
  app.use(express.session());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.signedCookies.cat) {
    res.cookie('cat', 'boo', {signed: true});
    console.log('setting cookie');
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
    return res.end('cookie set');
  }

  res.end('signed cookie: ' + req.signedCookies.cat);
});
```

When I use the browser to hit `localhost:3000` I get the first desired response`cookie set`.
I check the browser cookies and the cookie has been set.
When I use the same browser to hit `localhost:3000` again I get the same response 'cookie set'.
The request does not seem to pickup on the cookie.

So in another file I copied/paste the exact above code and switched ports to `3080`.
When that goes through the second response produces `signed cookie: boo'.

Then if I refresh `localhost:3000` the response is `signed cookie: boo`.
Why does this happen?  Is there caching going on that shouldn't?
Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE_01**
Even if I do a `req.signedCookies.session` immediately after setting the cookie I get back `undefined`. The cookie does get signed because there is an additional `.` followed by a bunch of random letters and numbers.  It's not being assigned to `req.signedCookies`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookie in the browsers is:
`boo.o5SqHrxUOZkyNLdIBqIZrfog6jXYJkP78M99IMbrnDA`

By updating to express 3.0.3 the cookie becomes:
`s:boo.o5SqHrxUOZkyNLdIBqIZrfog6jXYJkP78M99IMbrnDA`

The problem is fixed after updating.